# How to connect to Docker Toolbox mysql container from workbench in Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

I already have a MySQL running container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                               NAMES
55aaf065c4ce        mysql/mysql-server   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   8 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   vigorous_gates
```

It has already a mysql password and I can connect to the service using docker exec, but not from my laptop.

What am I missing?

But mysql workbench won't connect.

Comment: By the way I've looked several other threads, with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275

Comment: No, that is not the problem. The problem is the 10061 error code from mysql workbench. I have docker toolbox running with a mysql container running. I've created a user and granted all privileges, I've restarted the container, I've followed exactly this:
https://codereviewvideos.com/course/docker-tutorial-for-beginners/video/docker-mysql-tutorial
Nothing works.

Comment: I've also tried with the IP 172.17.0.2 that docker inspect gives but is unreacheable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Didn't know the Docker machine IP, found it using `docker-machine ip` and then added another user to MySQL just not to use root, with % for all IPs allowed, granted privileges, flushed them and restarted container.